# Ordinary Differential Equation with a trigonometric function: radius of convergence?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

For the equation $$x^2y'' + y' + \tan(x)\,y = 0$$
establish lower bounds for the radius of convergence about the point $$x_0 = 1.$$